# How to write some text over a MaterialUI-icon

Tags: html, css, material-ui

[image: The image is the result which i want]I am working on a project in which i need to write a number over a icon.
I am using MaterialUI ModeComment icon and i want to write some text over it .
I tried the following things but didn't worked .

```
<ModeComment color='primary'>
  <Typography>2</Typography>
</ModeComment>
```

```
<ModeComment color='primary'>
   <span>2</span>
</ModeComment>
```

How can I do this? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: Preview]

---

Unfortunately, passing a `children` prop like you did will not work for material-ui's `Icon` component. It expects the [`children`](https://material-ui.com/api/icon/) to be the name of the icon font ligature.

A possible solution would be to create a custom component for your requirements - a `ModeCommentIconWithNumber` component maybe? Then it would have predefined styles to position its icon and number elements.

Below code would help you achieve what you want. You could modify this component, like accepting an `icon` prop to render or maybe a `color` prop that defines the color of the  icon.

```js
...
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    position: "relative",
    display: "inline-flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },
  icon: {
    fontSize: "2.5em"
  },
  count: {
    position: "absolute",
    lineHeight: 1,
    color: "#fff",
    top: "0.5em",
    fontSize: "1em"
  }
});

function ModeCommentIconWithNumber({ size = 16, count = 0 }) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root} style={{ fontSize: size }}>
      <ModeCommentIcon color="primary" className={classes.icon} />
      <Typography component="span" className={classes.count}>
        {count}
      </Typography>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit cool-monad-xo5r3]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Badge` of material ui. [link](https://material-ui.com/components/badges/#basic-badges)

```
<Badge 
  badgeContent={4} 
  anchorOrigin={{
    vertical: 'center',
    horizontal: 'center',
  }} 
  color="white">
   <ModeComment />
</Badge>
```

Comment: actually i want to write just over it not like a badge

Comment: center property is not there in anchorOrigin only left ,right ,top and bottom are there

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, there is no way to put text in icon (like a child as you did). You could put `Typography` outside the icon and use some css. Something like:

```
const styles = {
  typography: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: 13,
    position: "absolute",
    top: "1.2%",
    left: "2%"
  }
};

function TextIcon() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Typography style={styles.typography}>2</Typography>
      <ModeComment color="primary" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-merkle-hsutz?file=/index.js) a codesandbox example.

Comment: thanks for the consideration ..but the code is not working

Comment: @Deepakmaurya the code is working. Maybe you don't like the solution, but is working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Mui provide such customization. You could write text in parallel to icon and align it over the top of it using absolute position.